# Warning when transposing array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, julia, transpose

I recently moved from julia 0.4.5 to 0.5.0, and encountered a new issue, please help me understand if this is a bug or if I am missing some understanding here.

I want to create an array by repeating a row (a 1D array of strings) a certain number of times, and for that I use the `repmat` function. The row is read along with many others from a file (`readdlm`) before it is given as input to a function. In this function the row is initially handled as a vector. For `repmat` to make a 2D array of this I have to transpose it, as in the example below.

```
myRow=["1","2","3"]
myRow=myRow'
myArray=repmat(myRow',3)
```

However, when I execute the second line above I get a warning:

```
WARNING: the no-op `transpose` fallback is deprecated, and no more specific `transpose` method for String exists. Consider `permutedims(x, [2, 1])` or writing a specific `transpose(x::String)` method if appropriate.
```

The transposition is still executed, so my code still works, but I am not comfortable using code that gives me warnings of deprecation.

The error mesage above is the exact same as if I try to transpose a `String`, so i am suspecting that the error message is wrongly triggered when one tries to transpose an array of strings. When I transpose an array of other classes, e.g. integers, I don't trigger any warning.

Does anyone have a suggested explanation?

Comment: The suggested solution is `reshape(myRow, 1, length(myRow))`. Unfortunately the help message has not been updated yet (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/18320).

Comment: @Isaiah I recommend posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Isaiah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508431/isaiah) provided the answer:

```
reshape(myRow, 1, length(myRow))
```

as well as [a link to the explanation of what is going on.](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/18320)

Thank you!